# SceneKit: How can I position my 3D object from a 2D line obj?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, 3d, scenekit

Scene: I have a 2 lines which is parallel to each other (on 2D) drawn on a UIImageView using UIBezierPath. Then I added a SceneView over the UIImageview to display my 3D object. Now I need to position my 3d object (which I created using SketchUp [.dae file]) according to the lines drawn using the UIBezierPath and this should be done programmatically.

I having trouble finding the right formula for the the SceneNode's position, rotation, eulerAngles, transform or pivot. Because I think these attributes needs to calculated based on my lines.

I am able to convert 2D x,y coordinates to 3D coordinates using the 3D object's max and min Bounding Box.

```
SCNVector3 min = SCNVector3Zero;
SCNVector3 max = SCNVector3Zero;
[mySceneView.scene.rootNode getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];

float x = (pointA.x / CGRectGetMaxX(self.imageView.frame)) * max.x;
float y = ((CGRectGetMaxY(self.imageView.frame) - (CGRectGetMaxY(self.imageView.frame) - pointA.y)) / CGRectGetMaxY(self.imageView.frame)) * max.y;
```

However I am having trouble finding the z-axis.

Here is my current output.[image]

and my expected output should be like this.

[image]

Comment: Hi , I am stuck with the same part. Have you got any solution for this? Please let me know.